# Application Blocked by Security Settings - Expired Certificate from IBM Canada

Tags: certificate, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

Last week I started seeing an Application Blocked by Security Settings dialog when running droid or iPhone previews.  The detail says  Your security settings have blocked and app signed with an expired or not yet valid certificate from running.

Following the prompts for more info lead me to a second dialog calling out the cordovaFileApplet as the culprit, and to a certificate from IBM Canada Limited that expired Aug 29 2014, which I can see in my Java Console on my Mac.  That date lines up with when I started seeing this dialog.  A secondary symptom was a warning in the browser after a few minutes about an applet crash.

If it matters, I'm running OS X 10.9.4, Java 1.7.0_67, WL 6.2.0.0  on Luna Java EE 4.4.0, but I saw the same errors with WL6.2 on Kepler.

I got rid of the dialog by adding my server to my exception site list, so problem solved, kind of.

My question is whether this is more than just a personal problem, and what the "production" solution is, since our dev server IP addresses change.  Is there a new certificate from IBM Canada that needs to be distributed so others are not bugged by this?  How do we distribute this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the Mobile Browser Simulator's Certificate expired on Aug 29 2014, this blocks the applet by default.  Until an updated certificate is distributed please use the addition of the server to your exception site list as a workaround.